# how can i check if number entered is prime and if not find its prime factors in python?

Tags: python

Write a Python (or R) program that asks the user to enter an integer (X), then:

Determines if X is prime or not
If X is not prime, compute and print the factors of that integer X
Evaluate and print the equation Y=8X²+ 1, for X values from -5 to 5 using the range function and for loop

Comment: Getting the factors of the number will also tell you if it's prime. If the factors are only 1 and the number, it's prime.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't do your homework for you.  What have you tried?